# access parent methods in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I have two files, `main.py` and `ColorPoint.py`. The last one consists of `Point` class and `ColorPoint` class inherited from `Point` class. Is there any way to access `Point`'s methods from `main.py` file?

For example I have two methods `__str__` in `Point` and `ColorPoint` classes. But I want to print `colorpoint` object as just `Point`:

```
print colorpoint # gives output from Point class, not ColorPoint class
```

I know how to access parent methods from class via `super`, but how to do the same from `main`, not from class?

Comment: This is an unusual request - can you give some more information on what you're trying to achieve, maybe there's a better way to to what you're trying...

Comment: `Point.__str__(colorpoint)` ?

Comment: Rusty, yes - exactly what I wanted!!!

Comment: If you want the parent class's `__str__` implementation, why implement it on the subclass at all?

Comment: @ovod well, you probably shouldn't use this type of stuff. You should rethink your design, this is kind of a dirty-hackish code.

Comment: jonrsharpe, I understood that there is a better way to complete my need. But I have a "issue" which i want to resolve))) For educational reasons only)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [the thingy formerly known as unbound methods](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.4/lib/typesmethods.html).

In python, when you call a method via the class, the "self" is not automatically bound (how should it know on which instance to operate?), you have to pass it yourself. And that "self" does not have to be an actual instance of the class.

So you can do:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __repr__(self):
...      return "I'm A's __repr__ operating on a " + self.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def __repr__(self):
...      return "I'm B's __repr__"
... 
>>> b=B()
>>> b
I'm B's __repr__
>>> A.__repr__(b)
"I'm A's __repr__ operating on a B"
```

And to fully meet your specs, you can also find out the parent class which methods to call programatically at runtime, for example like so *(not a safe implementation, for educational purposes only, will break on more complex setup, do not use sometig like this in production, this is horrible code, disclaimerdisclaimerdisclaimer)*:

```
>>> b.__class__.__base__.__repr__(b)
"I'm A's __repr__ operating on a B"
```